# Serial port timeout using MSDOS API

Tags: serial-port, timeout, dos

I'm trying to write some 16 bit assembly code to deal with serial port communications (using interrupt 21h functions 03h and 04h).

I already wrote code to send and receive bytes, but I'd like to implement an optional timeout to reception. I can already cancel transmission by implementing a break interrupt handler in 23h, but reception seems unhindered by this (probably blocking in kernel code to receive bytes on serial port).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: #offtopic May I ask you about the reason for dealing with such an ancient technologies and approach?

Comment: Easiest way to transfer files between DOS machines without dealing with floppy images is Xmodem, and also for fun, enjoyment and learning :D

Mainly for the latter.

Comment: I think you'll need to talk the hardware directly. Also there's plenty of free MS-DOS software that already implements XMODEM, or better yet, the ZMODEM protocol.

Comment: Considering I'm halfway through the implementation, I'd like to finish it. It's not that I really need a fast and efficient way to transfer files, its also for educational purposes: I'd like to know how to implement this.

Comment: You're a long way from completing it. You'll need to rewrite it to talk to the hardware directly.

Comment: OK, can you provide a more in-detail answer and post it as such so I can accept it?